# Can I get absolute device orientation on chrome on Android?

Tags: javascript, html, device-orientation

When I experimented with device orientation a year ago, it was behaving differently on ios safari and android chrome. 
Chrome was showing absolute values, relative North, while safari was showing relative values + webkitCompassHeading which is absolute.

But now it seems that chrome has changed, it's not showing absolute anymore, only relative. Meaning that alpha is relative to the first measure on the page, not the north pole.

Is it now impossible to read the compass heading in Chrome?

Or is there a way to read the compass?

For instance: can I somehow change how device orientation behaves do that it returns absolute:true?

Comment: *"Is it now impossible to read the compass heading in Chrome?"* Does that really seem likely to you? Why not ask (or rather, search for) the simple version of your question: How do I read the compass in Chrome?

Comment: This sounds more like a complaint than a technical question.

Comment: I realize that I phrased myself a little bad, what I mean is: the values returned from deviceorientation is absolute:false. Is there a way to get absolute:true so I can read the compass heading?

Answer (score 0):

I found that there's deviceorientationabsolute, hidden behind an experimental flag:
https://codereview.chromium.org/1416123002/

Answer (score 0):

This page from Google answers the question: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/device-orientation-changes

ie, that the API has indeed changed from absolute to relative. It discusses how to still access absolute values, as well as including some thoughts about cross browser / device compatibility.